# Error: Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I need to read an email from Gmail app so i download mail.jar , activation.jar and additional.jar and put them inside libs  under app folder and it's all Ok but whe i run the application i got
**Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.**

So  i removed them and replace them by this dependencies:

```
  implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.2'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.2'
```

but i got the same error any help?

Comment: Try the instructions on the [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your proguard file

```
#maybe
#-keep public class com.sun.mail.** { public *; }
-dontwarn com.sun.mail.**
```